# Sequelize injecting id attribute into select clause breaking query

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I was able to summarize multiple attributes on a table without grouping like so:

```js
Post.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.literal(`COALESCE(SUM("Post"."characterCount"), 0)`), 'totalCharacters'],
    [sequelize.literal(`COUNT(DISTINCT "Post"."userId")`), 'userCount'],
  ],
});
```

Which produced this query:

```sql
SELECT 
  COALESCE(SUM("Post"."characterCount"), 0) AS "totalCharacters", 
  COUNT(DISTINCT "Post"."userId") AS "userCount"
FROM 
  "Posts" AS "Post";
```

All is well.

But when I join another table to add some conditions, Sequelize is injecting another attribute into the SELECT clause, which is no longer a valid query...

The sequelize:

```js
Post.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.literal(`COALESCE(SUM("Post"."characterCount"), 0)`), 'totalCharacters'],
    [sequelize.literal(`COUNT(DISTINCT "Post"."userId")`), 'userCount'],
  ],
  include: [
    {association: 'user', attributes: []},
  ],
  where: {
    '$user.role$': {[Op.not]: 'admin'},
  },
});
```

The sql:

```sql
SELECT 
  "Post"."id",
  COALESCE(SUM("Post"."characterCount"), 0) AS "totalCharacters", 
  COUNT(DISTINCT "Post"."userId") AS "userCount"
FROM 
  "Posts" AS "Post" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Users" AS "user" ON "Post"."userId" = "user"."id" 
WHERE 
  "user"."role" != 'admin';
```

Is there a way to get it to not add `"Post"."id"` to the SELECT clause?

[Related Github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7534)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT "Post"."userId")`, to make code clearer.

Comment: And your `LEFT JOIN` returns regular `INNER JOIN` result. Move the `"user"` condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah my actual situation is more like `WHERE user.role != 'admin' OR user.role IS NULL`. Tried to simplify as much as possible for this question to be understandable. This bit isn't relevant to the problem Sequelize is causing.

Comment: Have you tried `raw: true` as suggested in the Github issue?

Comment: @Emma Oh wow I did miss that actually... so yeah that does work for my situation. Thanks!
Should be noted that this returns POJO instead of Sequelize instances.

Comment: yeah, `raw: true`'s main feature is to return a plain object but in your case, it is more of unwanted side effect.  If there is any other way to solve your issue than this  , that would be the best. However, I have not yet found any.

Comment: @Emma If you want to make that into an answer I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a Github link, please try adding `raw: true`. Though, adding `raw: true` to solve the Sequelize automatic addition of an extra column doesn't really make sense. Because  this option is to return a plain object instead of Sequelize wrapped instance.

Therefore, in your case, it *somehow* solves to remove the extra column, however, it returns a plain object which perhaps a unwanted side effect.